# How is line voltage measured?

Tags: voltage, measurement, mains

When people say that the line voltage in the US is 120 volts, do they mean amplitude, Vpp or Vrms?

Comment: They are referring to Vrms for the line to neutral voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line voltage is measured in Vrms, that is why you need a 350V or higher rated cap if you are going to rectify 220VAC.